# Publish ClickOnce using the Internet

Tags: clickonce, visual-studio-2015

I've seen this asked a couple times but there's either no answer at all, or the answer uses VS 2012 or earlier when this was allowed. It seems Microsoft removed this feature in VS 2013.

Is there any way to publish a ClickOnce application as a web page?

Edit: Here's the feedback report for the removal of the feature:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1013145/vs-2013-4-rc-publish-xbap-via-http

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XBAPs were removed, but you can still publish to an HTTP/HTTPS hosted endpoint.  All XBAPs gave you were browser-hosted apps, but the deployment mechanism can still apply for a desktop experience with ClickOnce.

For example, I use Azure Blob Storage to host the published files, using the publish.htm as the front-end to send users.  Each time I publish, I have to push the files to the blob store, but it's very easily automated.  User's are directed to go to: http://*your-blob-store-url*/publish.htm

The approach I use is based on this article: [How to host a ClickOnce deployment in Azure Blob Storage](https://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2011/02/13/how-to-host-a-clickonce-deployment-in-azure-blob-storage/)

Comment: Thank you, I will follow the article.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the feature is still there.

This guide explains how to specify a web page [How to: Specify a Publish Page for a ClickOnce Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ws69w0k3(v=vs.120).aspx)

Comment: That's for changing the generated publish.htm file. That's fine and all but doesn't relate to actually having Visual Studio publish the application to an HTTP address. I added a bug link in the question.

Comment: I think you can publish to an ftp address. Is that an option for you?